# When is "have to" pronounced /ˈhæf tə/?

Tags: pronunciation, verbs, modal-verbs

The OALD gives two pronunciations for [have to](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/have+to): /ˈhæf tə/ and /ˈhæv tə/. It also gives two pronunciations for *has to* (/ˈhæz tə/, /ˈhæs tə/) and *had to* (/ˈhæd tə/, /ˈhæt tə/).

When is *have to* pronounced /ˈhæf tə/? Does the pronunciation change basing on the following word, as it happens with *the*, or are there other *rules*?

Comment: There's a fuller exploration on [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/). Related variations in pronunciation also occur with other verbs, including *used to* when it means *was accustomed to*, and *was supposed to* when it means *ought to have*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pronounced /ˈhæf tə/ when it acts as a semi-modal, equivalent to must, AND the two words fall together. In all other circumstances it is pronounced as /ˈhæv tə/.

---

ADD: Actually, the *to* in /ˈhæv tə/ will in most cases be pronounced /tᵿ/, but that's a very minor point.

---

> I **/ˈhæf tə/** tell you the truth: I have no idea what you're talking about.
>    I **/ˈhæv/, /tə/** tell you the truth, no idea what you're talking about.
>    We **/ˈhæv/ /tə/** the left, the Colosseum; /tə/ the right, the Arch of Constantine.
>    We **/ˈhæv/ /tə/** that end instituted a new policy.
>    I **/ˈhæf tə/** go to Ottawa tomorrow.
>    <sup>**?**</sup>I **/ˈhæv/, /tə/** my dismay, to go to Ottawa tomorrow.

You're very unlikely to hear the last one. It's not formally "incorrect", but only a very literate speaker or writer, familiar with similar uses of full modals, would think that *have to* might be be deployed with an adverbial between the auxiliary and the lexical verb; and only a speaker or writer with a tin ear would allow himself to do so.

Comment: What is the pronunciation of _have to_ in "You simply have to get a new job"? I ask because in two if your examples, _to_ is part of a parenthetical.

Comment: @kiamlaluno With /f/ = "You simply must get a new job." Almost any prepositional phrase in that position is going to be adjunctive, and thus virtually by definition 'parenthetical'. I've added a couple of exx that are less emphatically bracketed.

Comment: To be clearer: I am referring to what said from the [OALD about _have to_ (modal verb)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/have+to). Are there any cases where the verb is modal, but it is not semi-modal? I ask because you say, "It is pronounced /ˈhæf tə/ when it acts as a semi-modal, equivalent to must."

Comment: When I said _parenthetical_, I should have said _parenthesis_. Clearly, I would not pronounce _have, to_ as /ˈhæf tə/ because the comma, and "I have no idea" is not using _have to_ as modal verb.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno It's called a "semi-modal" because unlike the full modals it a) takes a to-infinitive, not a bare infinitive, and b)it has non-finite forms and can be used modally in constructions using those forms: *I will have to go*, *I have had to go*, *I am having to go*. Note that the deviant pronunciation occurs with the infinitive: *I will hafta go*.

Comment: We are back to the question: In which cases is _have to_ (the modal verb) pronounced /ˈhæf tə/ instead of /ˈhæv tə/? Since the dictionary is talking of _have to_ as modal verb, I assume that both the pronunciations are for _have to_ used as modal verb.

Comment: @kiamlaluno As a modal *have* is pronounced with the /f/ whenever it is immediately followed by the *to* marking the infinitive to which it is auxiliary. No exceptions: under those circumstances pronunciation with a /v/ is hypercorrective. In other circumstances - e.g., suffixed constructions (*having to*), prepositional *to* (*have to our left*) - it is pronounced with /v/. The same is true, mutatis mutandis, of 3 sgl *has to*: unvoiced-s /hæstə/ when followed immediately by *to* of marked infinitive, voiced-s /hæz/ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

StoneyB has explained well the contexts in which *hafta* is used, but I'm going to shed some light on why 'have to' is pronounced *hafta*.

I have explained it in some other answers as well, such as [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248446/106592) [Why does the B change to a P when *-tion* is added to 'absorb'].

**Voicing assimilation** is what happened here. In voicing assimilation, one of the two adjacent sounds changes its voicing. It's rather difficult to pronounce two adjacent obstruents that disagree in voicing. The /v/ at the end of 'have' is voiced while the /t/ at the beginning of 'to' is voiceless, so the /v/ anticipates the /t/ and changes it's voicing (i.e. from voiced to voiceless) and becomes /f/ because /f/ is the voiceless counterpart of /v/.

- /hæv tə/ → /hæf tə/ (*hafta*)

The same thing happens to *has to*:

- /hæz tə/ → /hæs tə/ -- the /z/ changes its voicing and becomes /s/